# Performing an SQL query while waiting on an asyncronous operation generates an exception

Tags: sql, exception, asynchronous

The code I'm writing copies data from one table to another. It is possible the query may run for a long time so I'm performing an asynchronous query and while waiting I'm doing a count on the destination table to provide a status update.

The query that does the count is getting the following exception message...

**The command execution cannot proceed due to a pending asynchronous operation already in progress.**

So clearly what I'm doing is not allowed. So what are the rules for asynchronous SQL operations? Is there another way to get the status of the pending operation?

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder( _connectionString );
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;

using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( builder.ConnectionString ) )
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DestTable SELECT * FROM SourceTable";

    IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

    using( SqlConnection statusConnection = new SqlConnection( _connectionString ) )
    {
        while( !result.IsCompleted )
        {
            SqlCommand statusCommand = new SqlCommand();
            statusCommand.Connection = statusConnection;
            statusCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            statusCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DestTable";

            int currentRowCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            Thread.Sleep( 500 );
        }

        command.EndExecuteNonQuery( result );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag this question with the database product you're using (Oracle, SQL Server, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use the same command.

I think that you want to replace

```
int currentRowCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

with

```
int currentRowCount = (int)statusCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

You are attempting to use the same Statement, which should be blocked due to the first execution.